# QWebPage loadFinished signal not called when using thread?

Tags: pyqt4, qtwebkit, qthread

I am trying to execute a network request with webkit in a secondary thread and also do all the processing like scrapping data in the same thread. However, I am puzzled why the QWebPage's signal loadFinished is not connecting. Please enlighten me as I am still learning.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class HeadlessBrowser(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.page = QWebPage()

    def browse_page(self, url):
        qDebug('method browse_page called.') #This is called.
        url = QUrl(url)
        self.page.mainFrame().load(url)
        self.page.loadFinished.connect(self.process_page) #Not executed. Why?

    def process_page(self):
        qDebug('method process_page called.') #This is not called. Why?
        #Convert to html
        print(self.page.mainFrame().toHtml())

class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def run(self):

        br = HeadlessBrowser()
        br.browse_page('http://www.google.com')

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    thread = WorkerThread()
    thread.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me how you installed it? I'm facing the problem with installing it. Thanks.

Comment: @Krishnanunni: May I know what platform are you using? I am using windows and the binary installer will install it automatically if you have python installed. Link of the installer is [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download).